# A polynomial map $p:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ extends to a continuous map $S^2\to S^2$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I know that one-point compactification of $\mathbb C$ is $\mathbb C\cup \{\infty\}\approx S^2$

So, if someone talks about continuous extention of given complex polynomial map, should I think about sending $z\to\infty$ in $C\cup \{\infty\}\approx S^2$

I am lost around the topics. So I want to know what is the proper way of extending given polynomial $p:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$, continuously to $\tilde p: S^2\to S^2$. How to prove existence of such extension?

Comment: Set $p(\infty) = \infty$ and prove that it is continuous!

Comment: If the polynomial is non constant then $\lim_{z\to\infty} |p(z)|=\infty$. Thus (if we remember how the metric on $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ is defined) we can extend it by sending $\infty$ to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

If $p\colon\Bbb C\longrightarrow\Bbb C$ is a non-constant polynomial map, then extending $p$ to a continuous map $\tilde p\colon S^2\longrightarrow S^2$ can be done in one and only one way if we want that $\tilde p$ is continuous; it's to define $\tilde p(\infty)=\infty$. Of course, if you are not interested in continuity, then $\tilde p(\infty)$ can be any element of $S^2$ that you want.

And if $p$ is the constant map $\omega$ ($\omega\in\Bbb C$), then define $\tilde p(\infty)=\omega$ (again, if you want that $\tilde p$ is continuous).

Comment: The point that I don't understant why "can be done in one and only one way if we ant that $\tilde p$ is continuous" part happens?

Comment: Because if $p$ is polynomial and non-constant, then $\lim_{z\to\infty}p(z)=\infty$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos My complex analysis is weak,  should that limit be interpreted as the limit of $|z|\to \infty$,  i.e. direction independent?

Comment: Yes. It means that, for every $M>0$, there is some $N>0$ such that$$|z|>N\implies\bigl|f(z)\bigr|<M.$$